Error in buildozer when i compile apk file
I wrote the code for mobile application for Android using python and kivy.
But when I tried to make apk file using buildoser.spec, it errors.
Please, help me. I develop the mobile application for the first time.
The code of an error
Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy==2.3.0,kivymd==1.2.0', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/mnt/c/Users/dasd8/Downloads/BinarytoDecimal-main/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']

I read at the forums in the Internet that this mistake can be, when there are spaces in the path of the directory. But my path to the directory has no spaces. 
I don't know what to do.
